# karma unit test: How to resolve 'Error: No provider for "framework:karma-sinon"! (Resolving: framework:karma-sinon)'?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, webpack, karma-jasmine, sinon

I am trying to add the karma-sinon module to my angularjs unit test, this is a fragment of my karma config:

```
frameworks: ['mocha','karma-sinon', 'chai', 'fixture'],
```

it also contains:

```
plugins: [
      require("karma-chai"),
      require("karma-chrome-launcher"),
      require("karma-coverage"),
      require("karma-mocha"),
      require("karma-mocha-reporter"),
      require("karma-sourcemap-loader"),
      require("karma-webpack"),
      require("karma-fixture"),
      require("karma-json-fixtures-preprocessor"),
      require("karma-sinon")
    ],
```

How can I resolve this error and start unit testing with sinon? Goal is to use  a spy statement so I am open to other solutions.

Comment: Kinda stupid but I should ask - you have karma-sinon installed?

Comment: No problem, yes it is installed.